# How to close an already open Word docx from Excel vb code modules?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to close an Word docx document that is open in Windows from Excel spreadsheet vb code code.  I haven't found a way to close an open word document sitting in the background.  I've been dabbling with killing the file first and then creating an other word doc...but since the word doc is open, I think that the killing can't take place.  Any ideas on how to either close a Word doc open in Windows, or kill it somehow?  Any assitence would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/Release Word object in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177412/close-release-word-object-in-vba)